# Java Thread drives CPU to 100%

Tags: java, multithreading, csv

I have rewritten this many times but I could not find a solution to this problem for a while. Some other Class writes *gps.log* file with lines like:

```
2014-09-02 10:23:13    35.185604    33.859077
2014-09-02 10:23:18    35.185620    33.859048
```

I am trying to read the last line of the file and update a text field in the user interface. The `Thread` below is overdriving the CPU into 85-100%. 
I keep the file very tiny (100 lines - < 5KB). I have been working with CSV for a long time, and I think reading this file every 3 seconds should not have this footprint on the CPU. Although I have been reading huge CSV files in the past it is the first time I have this issue now that I try to update the User Interface every couple seconds. Am I doing something wrong with how I am updating the text field? Any ideas?
Thanks for looking.

```java
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        while (true) {       
            Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (Exception e) { }

                            BufferedReader gpslog = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("log/gps.log"));
                            String line = "";
                            String lastLine = "";
                            int i=0;
                            while (line != null) {
                                i++;
                                lastLine = line;
                                line = gpslog.readLine();
                            }
                            //System.out.println(lastLine);
                            gpslog.close();
                            if (lastLine != null) { txtGPSStatus.setText(lastLine); }
                            //If more than 100 gps entries, flush the file
                            if (i>100) {
                                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("log/gps.log");
                                writer.close();
                            }

                        } catch (IOException e1) {
                            log.error(e1);
                        } 
                    }
            });
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Thread main loop use an async API... so it runs at full speed and should create a lot of async task?

Comment: Followed an answer in StackOverflow on how to update a SWT component in real time. I am not familiar with that API.

Comment: `while(true) {create a new thread that does work}`

Comment: Exactly, you are queuing a bunch of async runnables in an infinite loop. They will execute all the time. Just move that outer while(true) to the inner run method.

Comment: Never worked with SWT but I think only txtGPSStatus.setText(lastLine); should be put in async execution.

Comment: Yes Tyco, it looks like. I moved the while loop as Thomas suggested to the inside of run() and the GUI is not working. I remember from the question I read here on SO, it has to do with how the operating system handles requests to redraw UI components.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { }` is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: From what's above, the quickest solution is probably to move the Thread.sleep() line to be inside the while(true) but outside the Display.getDefault()...  That way you'll create one instance of the Display task every 3000 seconds, which I think is what you want.

Comment: I should have logged it you are right. I thought to myself, if the Thread does not manage to sleep for 3 seconds then who cares ;) I don't have any interrupts or funky stuff in this case.

Comment: user1676075 I have tried that, same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move

try { Thread.sleep(3000); } catch (Exception e) { }

so it is just after

while(true) {

Then you will run, wait 3 secs, run, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a clear idea of what should be done by the background thread and what the UI thread is for!

```
Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                updateLog();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // restore interruption flag
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
});

private void updateLog() {
    String lastLine = readLastLogLine();
    Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            txtGPSStatus.setText(lastLine);
        }
    });
}
```